# Selection Sort Java -Arraylist

Tags: java, sorting

I have implemented selection sort in java using arraylist. This selection sort is only for integers . Please have a look and give feedback. can we improve it ?

```
package selectionSort;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SelectionSort {
private ArrayList<Integer> num_sort=new ArrayList<>();

public SelectionSort(ArrayList<Integer> userlist) {
    this.num_sort=userlist;
    sort_select();


}

public void sort_select() {
    //outer for loop to pick one element at a time
    //e.g if list is 20,12,3,4,5,6,98----this loop will first pick 20
    for(int i=0;i<this.num_sort.size();i++) {
        //assign that element as minimum
        //in our e.g 20 will be assigned min in first iteration
        int min=this.num_sort.get(i);
        int min_index=i;
        //go over the rest of the list and compare minimum by rest of list. if number smaller than min is found, then it is assigned as new min
        //so go over list starting from 12 and comparing 20 with each of them and finding the new min, in this case it will be  3
        for(int j=i+1;j<this.num_sort.size();j++) {
            if(this.num_sort.get(j)<min) {
                min=this.num_sort.get(j);
                min_index=j;

            }
        }
        if(i!=min_index) {
           exchange(i,min_index);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sorted entered are : ");
    for(int x:this.num_sort) {
        System.out.print(x+" ");
    }
}


// exchange the element at ith position with min
public void exchange(int current_elem,int new_min) {
    int temp=this.num_sort.get(current_elem);
    this.num_sort.set(current_elem, this.num_sort.get(new_min));
    this.num_sort.set(new_min, temp);

}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Enter how many numbers you want to sort");

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int num_count=in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers you want to sort");
    ArrayList<Integer> userlist=new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0;i<num_count;i++) {
        userlist.add(in.nextInt());
    }



    SelectionSort s=new SelectionSort(userlist);

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Style

1. Use proper styling. You should use more whitespaces, this will make your code more readable. Instead of `num_sort=new` use `num_sort = new`, insead of `i!=min_index` use `i != min_index`, etc
2. Follow the Java naming conventions: variable and function names should use *camelCase*, not *snake_case*.
3. You should include documentation that explains the user how the class is used. For example, without looking at the code I would not expect that creating a new instance of the class automatically sorts the list, so it is something you must make clear in the documentation.

### Comments

Commenting the code is good, but too many comments can make a simple function look complicated. The general rule is that **code tells you how, comments tell you why**.

For example, I think `int min = this.num_sort.get(i);` does not need to be commented; it's pretty clear that you are getting the *i-th* item of the list.

Also, leave a whitespace between `//` and the text, it's more readable.

### Code structure

It does not make sense to have this in a class; `new SelectionSort(userlist)` is not the way someone would expect to sort a list. I am going to make some recommendations that for the class design, but for the rest of the review I will restructurate the code so that it is more conventional.

As a user I expect `select_sort` to sort the list and that's all; I decide whether I want to print the list or not (what if I want to print it differently to you?). So you should move the printing code to the `main` function.

#### Class design

If you were to continue with the current class design, there must be some changes:

1. Do not sort the list in the construction. It is not the expected behaviour. Let the user call `sortSelect()`. Actually, I think `selectionSort()` would be a better name.
2. Is `exchange` a method that is meant to be used by the user? I don't think so, so make it `private` instead of `public` so only the class code can use it.
3. `num_sort` does not seem like an intuitive name; I had to look at the code to know what it is. Just calling it `list` would be better.
4. You don't care how the list is internally implemented, you only care that it is a list. So use the more generic `List` interface instead of `ArrayList`.
5. You are assigning your list twice: on `num_sort=new ArrayList<>()` and on `this.num_sort=userlist;`. The first one is not necessary, because it will always be replaced in the constructor. Furthermore, since you never reassign the list again, you should declare it `final`.

```java
private final List<Integer> list;

public SelectionSort(List<Integer> userList) {
    this.list = userList;
}
```

#### Alternative design

1. In my opinion, your selection sort algorithm should just be one `static` method that takes the list as input. That would make it similar to the `Collections.sort()` method that already exists in Java.
2. `Scanner` is a resource that must be closed. You can make Java close it automatically by using a [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

```java
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // your code
}
```

3. You can still keep the convenience method `exchange` (as `static` and taking the list as parameter), but since it is quite short and you only call it in one place I think you could just write the code directly. If you decide to keep the function, I would change the parameter names to just `i` and `j`, and the method name to `swap` (it's more common). Since it's the same doing `exchange(current_elem, new_min)` than `exchange(new_min, current_elem)` those parameter names do not make much sense. BUT you don't even need to implement that method, you can just use [`Collections.swap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap-java.util.List-int-int-)

### Final code

```java
/**
 * Sorts the given list using a selection sort algorithm.
 * @param list The list to be sorted.
 */
public static void selectionSort(final List<Integer> list) {
    // outer for loop to pick one element at a time
    // e.g if list is 20,12,3,4,5,6,98----this loop will first pick 20
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int min = list.get(i);
        int minIndex = i;
        // Go over the rest of the list and compare minimum by rest of list. If number smaller than min is found, then it is assigned as new min
        // So go over list starting from 12 and comparing 20 with each of them and finding the new min, in this case it will be  3
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list.get(j) < min) {
                min = list.get(j);
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        if (i != minIndex) {
           Collections.swap(list, i, minIndex);
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Enter how many numbers you want to sort");
        int count = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the numbers you want to sort");
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            list.add(in.nextInt());
        }

        selectionSort(list);

        System.out.println("Sorted entered are: ");
        for (int x : list) {
            System.out.print(x + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comments @eric.m. Will take care of all these